# Custom Lookup and Group By

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

TLDR: Why group by clauses are disabled in lookups when the field using the lookup is not empty?

I want to do a custom lookup on a field in a form. The table `CTable` looks like this:

```
Val Spec
------------
A   alpha
A   beta
A   gamma
B   delta
C   epsilon
```

The look up only concerns the `Val` column which is defined using an EDT with a basic relationship on it: `Val == CTable.Val`

The lookup obviously gives me a list like this:

```
A
A
A
B
C
```

Let's to a group by to get rid of all the duplicated As, I thought!
Something along the lines of:

```
QueryBuildDataSource.orderMode(OrderMode::GroupBy);
QueryBuildDataSource.addGroupByField(fieldNum(CTable, Val));
```

Now comes the strange behaviour I have and the actual point of my question. On an empty field, the group by is correctly executed and I get this:

```
A
B
C
```

Now let's select "A" in the lookup, then perform the lookup *again* because I wanted to click on "B" instead. The group by is now disabled for unknown reasons and I get the same look up results as the first I had before.

Why is it so? How can I overcome that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same question and usefull answer:
http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/t/63438.aspx

> You can disable this behavior by setting useLookupValues in SysTableLookup to false. Unfortunately I don't know exactly why AX does that. I suspect that it changes OrderMode to OrderBy.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem yesterday.

I guess this code is in "init" maybe?

```
QueryBuildDataSource.orderMode(OrderMode::GroupBy);
QueryBuildDataSource.addGroupByField(fieldNum(CTable, Val));
```

I had to add my "GroupBy" code (above) to the executeQuery method, becuase the following line was removing the groupBys from my query (I checked this using breakpoints);

```
qbsSum.sortClear();
```

If you use breakpoints I would expect your GroupBy options are being cleared before the query executes again.

Comment: No it is not in the init. It is in the method at the table level which will perform the lookup. This method takes a form stringControl as a parameter, uses a SysTableLookup object to perform the lookup based on a local query object. This local query object has the Group By Clause on it. There is no visible "executeQuery" method but there is a "performLookup" at the end of the method.

Comment: I would expect you are experiencing the same issue if it works once until the query runs again - before the query runs (ie when you click B) add the group by code to QueryBuildDataSource again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This helped me:
`sysTableLookup.parmUseLookupValue(False);`